# how to connect with Informix DB docker image from C#

Tags: c#, docker, informix

I am new to the Informix DBMS. I have to connect to an Informix database which I am running using one dDocker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/informix-developer-database/) on Windows 10.
Please suggest how to connect to this server using C# and an ODBC driver.

Comment: You will need to expose the Informix ports (9088 for SQLI connections) as described here (https://github.com/informix/informix-dockerhub-readme/blob/master/12.10.FC12/informix-developer-database.md) and then use the pod ip and exposed port in your ODBC/C# connection string.

Comment: Thanks jsagrera for the response can u please help me with commands